# MySQLi random and temporary fatal error

Tags: php, mysqli, intermittent

I have an environment where I use beanstalkd and pheanstalk to queue and process jobs asynchronously. One of my workers is passed a MySQL table name, and row id, along with other information. That worker then updates that row of that table.

This works fine 99% of the time. However, occasionally my worker crashes with:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /path/to/file.php on line 62
```

As mentioned, this same line executes fine 99% of the time, but crashes every so often. The job it crashed on is not yet deleted and stays in the queue to be reprocessed by another worker. So when I restart the worker, it processes the **same** job it crashed on just moments earlier without issue.

My PHP looks something like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `database`.`$table` SET `Limit` = ? WHERE `D_ID` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("si", $Limit, $rowID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

The best I can figure is that because this is asynchronous, some other process happens to be locking that table/row at the time of execution. I would imagine the MySQL query to just wait for it's turn though and not out right crash.

Unfortunately, if this is the case, I have no way of testing or even fixing it, so I need a work around. If this is not the case, I need some guidance as to what the cause is and how to troubleshoot/fix it.

**Update**
As suggested in the comments, I checked the mysql error code and error message. The result is:

```
(2006) MySQL server has gone away
```

From the sounds of it, the database connection has failed, however, when the worker deletes the job and grabs the next one, it works just fine using the same connection. What does this mean?

Comment: Implement some error control to find out exactly why preparing of the statement didn’t work.

Comment: Specifically, see [the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) under "First stage: prepare".

Comment: I've gone ahead and updated my question with the error code/message.

Comment: are your mixing a prepared statment with concat stuff? how do you know that $table has a valid value?

Comment: @LuisSiquot I am mixing prepared statement with concatenated data for the table name, as I've never been able to get a prepared statement to accept a variable table name. The value of $table is valid and generated by the server. The worker cannot run (and hence the mysqli cannot be executed) without $table being present and valid. Also, just to be on the safe side, I am outputting the table name (and $Limit, $rowID) with the mysql error. The values are present and valid.

Answer (score -1):

You lacked ". ." to concat $table.
The prepared statement should be:

```php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `database`.`".$table."` SET `Limit` = ? WHERE `D_ID` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("si", $Limit, $rowID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

The prepare function fails if the query is not 100% perfect.

Comment: That won't make any difference: `"The $variable in double quoted strings are evaluated"`, i.e. it is the same as writing `"The " . $variable . " in double quoted strings are evaluated"`

Comment: Ye my bad. The variables on bind_param should be new, literally it should be `bind_param("si",$l, $rid);`
then the next lines you should give the value, so `$l = $Limit; $rid = $rowID;` then run the execute function.

Sorry for the late answer.